# Scrapy is not crawling any URLs

Tags: python, scrapy

I placed my code in scrapy shell to test my xpath everything seems ok. However I cannot see why is 0 crawls. Here is the log output:

> 2019-02-27 18:04:47 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.1 started
>   (bot: jumia) 2019-02-27 18:04:47 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions:
>   lxml 4.3.0.0, libxml2 2.9.9, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.1, w3lib
>   1.20.0, Twisted 18.9.0, Python 2.7.15+ (default, Nov 28 2018, 16:27:22) - [GCC 8.2.0], pyOpenSSL 18.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.0j  20 Nov
>   2018), cryptography 2.4.2, Platform
>   Linux-4.19.0-kali1-amd64-x86_64-with-Kali-kali-rolling-kali-rolling
>   2019-02-27 18:04:47 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
>   {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'jumia.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES':
>   ['jumia.spiders'], 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'BOT_NAME': 'jumia'}
>   2019-02-27 18:04:47 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
>   ['scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage', 
>   'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats', 
>   'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole', 
>   'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats'] 2019-02-27 18:04:47
>   [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
>   ['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats'] 2019-02-27
>   18:04:47 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
>   ['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware'] 2019-02-27 18:04:47
>   [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: [] 2019-02-27
>   18:04:47 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened 2019-02-27 18:04:47
>   [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min),
>   scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min) 2019-02-27 18:04:47
>   [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on
>   127.0.0.1:6029 2019-02-27 18:04:47 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished) 2019-02-27 18:04:47 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO:
>   Dumping Scrapy stats: {'finish_reason': 'finished',  'finish_time':
>   datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 27, 17, 4, 47, 950397),  'log_count/DEBUG':
>   1,  'log_count/INFO': 7,  'memusage/max': 53383168, 
>   'memusage/startup': 53383168,  'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019,
>   2, 27, 17, 4, 47, 947520)} 2019-02-27 18:04:47 [scrapy.core.engine]
>   INFO: Spider closed (finished)

Here is my spider code:

```
    import scrapy
    from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
    from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose
    from scrapy.loader.processors import TakeFirst
    from jumia.items import JumiaItem


    class ProductDetails (scrapy.Spider):
        name = "jumiaProject"
        start_url = ["https://www.jumia.com.ng/computing/hp/"]

        def parse (self, response):

            search_results = response.css('section.products.-mabaya > div')

            for product in search_results: 

                product_loader = ItemLoader(item=JumiaItem(), selector=product)

                product_loader.add_css('brand','h2.title > span.brand::text')

                product_loader.add_css('name', 'h2.title > span.name::text')

                product_loader.add_css('link', 'a.link::attr(href)')


                yield product_loader.load_item()
```

Here is my `items.py`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Define here the models for your scraped items
#
# See documentation in:
# https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html

import scrapy
from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose
class JumiatesteItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    name  = scrapy.Field()
    brand = scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field()
    link  = scrapy.Field()
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct variable name in your Spider should be `start_urls`, not `start_url`. Because of the wrong name it doesn't detect any URLs.

Comment: Thank you for good information, it worked. I cannot believe that I missed the s. Thanks alot.